# ZonedDateTime now function mandatorily contains second value

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time, zoneddatetime

My code requires the current UTC time in String format.

```
String date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).withNano(0).toString();
```

This works fine in most cases except for when the time has zero seconds value.

```
Normal output: 2018-03-07T11:33:09Z
Problem output: 2018-03-06T11:33Z
```

It skips printing the second time. How can I force the seconds to be printed even if they are zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formatter to always print the seconds-part:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
String s = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).withNano(0).format(dtf);
System.out.println(s); // 2018-03-20T16:15:07Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `DateTimeFormatter` like the one [suggested by Meno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152807), you don't even need to set the nanos value to zero:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
String formatted = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(fmt);
System.out.println(formatted); // 2018-03-08T13:33:52Z
```

That's because the formatter prints only the fields specified in the format. In this case, it's using `HH:mm:ss`, which means **"hours:minutes:seconds"**. As the fraction of seconds is not in the pattern, they're not printed, so there's no need to call `withNano`.

This may sound like a minor detail, but as all those classes are immutable, methods like `withNano` always create a new object, and in this case you don't need to, so using the formatter not only gives you the desired output, but it also avoids the creation of unnecessary objects (with only one `ZonedDateTime`, this might sound irrelevant, but in a scenario with lots of dates being formatted this can make some difference, IMO).

I'd call `withNano(0)` only if I really want to set this field to zero. If I just don't want to print it when formatting, I wouldn't call it.